# How to use sql def variable

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to declare a variable in a simple sql script to create some tables in a schema, but it's not working.

Here's a snippet of my sql script:

```
DEF SCHEMA_NAME = MY_SCHEMA;

CREATE TABLE &SCHEMA_NAME.BOOK
(
    BOOK_ID            INTEGER
);
```

That's creating a table with the table name `MY_SCHEMABOOK` instead of a table named `BOOK` in the schema `MY_SCHEMA`.

The script output in Oracle Sql Developer says:

```
old:CREATE TABLE &SCHEMA_NAME.BOOK
(
    BOOK_ID            INTEGER
)
new:CREATE TABLE MY_SCHEMABOOK
(
    BOOK_ID            INTEGER
)
table MY_SCHEMABOOK created.
```

If that helps. Also, it seems that changing it to `&SCHEMA_NAME..BOOK` does make it work like I want it to, but having to put two periods doesn't make sense to me. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: "&SCHEMA_NAME"."BOOK" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SET CON[CAT] {. | c | ON | OFF}
>
> Sets the character used to terminate a substitution variable reference
>   when SQL*Plus would otherwise interpret the next character as a part
>   of the variable name.
>
> SQL*Plus resets the value of CONCAT to a period when you switch CONCAT on.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12040.htm#sthref2722

SQL Developer works the same way - your first period is interpreted as a substitution variable terminator. So, it is perfectly valid to use two consequent periods in this case.

Comment: Well, I guess I'll just do that then.